# Ionic 3 multi lines segments

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

This is my code:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedName" (ionChange)="nameSelected($event)">
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
      {{name}}
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

The list "names" has 12 items. I would like to show 3 "ion-segment-button" in each row.

Please any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach would be to pre-process your array of "names", then use a nested `*ngFor` to render them in groups of 3.

Here's an example illustrating the desired result:
https://embed.plnkr.co/qcyHUsjEhAVAU2q9Jxj8/
[image]

The main changes are in the TypeScript and HTML template; first the TS (I've mocked the array of 12 names inline but they just as easily could be returned via web service):

```
this.names = [
      {name: 'one'},
      {name: 'two'},
      {name: 'three'},
      {name: 'four'},
      {name: 'five'},
      {name: 'six'},
      {name: 'seven'},
      {name: 'eight'},
      {name: 'nine'},
      {name: 'ten'},
      {name: 'eleven'},
      {name: 'twelve'}
    ]
    this.segmentsPerRow = 3
    this.rows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.names.length / this.segmentsPerRow)).keys())
```

The notable portion is the last row that essentially splits the array into `rows` that each contain up to 3 names for your segment selector; you could customize the group size using the `segmentsPerRow` variable as well. Note if your total item count is not divisible by the `segmentsPerRow` value, the last row will just size each item accordingly to fill the available space.

Then the key changes to the HTML template:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedName" *ngFor="let i of rows">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let name of names | slice:(i*segmentsPerRow):(i+1)*segmentsPerRow">
        <ion-segment-button value="{{name.name}}">
          {{name.name}}
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ng-container>
    </ion-segment>
```

First the segment is repeated once for each row via `*ngFor="let i of rows"`, then within each segment, the 3 items therein get their own button per the Ionic markup; these are wrapped in an `ng-container` so as not to add unnecessary elements to the output.